# Get value of a particular cell in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe which has 1 row and 3 columns, namely start_date, end_date, end_month_id. I want to retrieve the value from first cell into a variable and use that variable to filter another dataframe.

[image]

I want to retrieve '2019-01-01' into a variable. How do I do that?
Here is what I have so far:

```
start_date = df1[0];
df2.filter(df2.date_reported >= start_date)
```

I am a beginner.

Comment: Is df1 a spark dataframe or python object ?

Answer (score 6):

If df1 is Spark DataFrame then, use `collect()` function for getting the same.
For example,

```
df1.collect()[Row number][Column number][0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you just gave the answer that I was searching from 1 day! This is what I did: y=df.collect()[8000]    print(y). But do you know if we can recall a row with a specific known value?

Answer (score 3):

Try This. take gives you an array of rows, and you can extract the value based on column name from Row object.

```
val start_date = df1.take(1)(0).getAs[String]("start_date")
```

Comment: May I know what was the issue with this?

Comment: 1 = row 1, 0 = column 0?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Using collect works but can be concerning when you have a dataframe with millions or billions of rows since collect grabs everything and puts it ALL into the head worked.

Better, if you can, to first filter the dataframe smaller before doing that in some way.

If the frame is sorted and you can guarantee it is in the first row, here is one method.

df.first().asDict()['col_name'] will get you a value.